# semidirect product, should the morphism act on the first or second element?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let us take two groups, $N$ and $H$, as well as a non-trivial homomorphism $\varphi:H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$.

Now let me define two further groups:
$$
G_R=(N\times H,\circledR)\,,\\
G_S=(N\times H,\circledS)\,,
$$
i.e., the underlying set is always $N\times H$, but we have two different group operations:
$$
(n_1,h_1)\mathbin{\circledR}(n_2,h_2)=\bigl(n_1\circ\varphi(h_1)(n_2),h_1\circ h_2\bigr)\,,\\
(n_1,h_1)\mathbin{\circledS}(n_2,h_2)=\bigl(\varphi(h_2^{-1})(n_1)\circ n_2,h_1\circ h_2\bigr)\,.
$$
As far as I can tell both $G_R$ and $G_S$ are well defined groups. Now some questions: What is the relation between the two definitions? Are they isomorphic or could they lead to different groups? (If yes, what is the isomorphism?) Is either of the two definitions considered more natural? (Would you define one or the other as $N\rtimes_\varphi H$?) [Or is this like with sesquilinear products where mathematicians/physicists seem to prefer having linearity in either the first or the second component?]

-- Edited to correct my mistake as pointed out by Derek Holt.

Comment: Th first definition is more natural because $\varphi(h_1)(n_2)$ corresponds to $h_1n_2h_1^{-1}$ in the internal semidirect product. As it stands, the second definition does not define a group because the operation is not associative. It would work if you replaced $\varphi(h_2)$ by $\varphi(h_2^{-1})$ in the definition. Then you are really just writing down what you would get if you wrote the elements as $(h,n)$ rather than $(n,h)$ so yes it is isomorphic to the group in the first definition.

Comment: Well it seems that I am stupid and that it should indeed be $\varphi(h_2^{-1})(n_1)\circ n_2$. Then an isomorphism $i:G_R\to G_S$ can be defined by $(n,h)\mapsto(\varphi(h^{-1})(n),h)$ such that $i\bigl((n_1,h_1)\mathbin{\circledR}(n_2,h_2)\bigr)=i\bigl((n_1,h_1)\bigr)\mathbin{\circledS}i\bigl((n_2,h_2)\bigr)$ and the two groups are equivalent. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $G_R$ and $G_S$ are isomorphic.
- $i:G_R\to G_S,\; (n,h)\mapsto(\varphi(h^{-1})(n),h)$ defines a possible isomorphism.
- $G_R$ could be considered more natural; its elements $(n,h)$ correspond to the ordering $n\circ h$ when viewed as an internal semidirect product, such that $(n_1\circ h_1)\circ(n_2\circ h_2)=(n_1\circ[h_1\circ n_2\circ h_1^{-1}])\circ(h_1\circ h_2)$ and therefore $\varphi(h_1)(n_1)=h_1\circ n_2\circ h_1^{-1}$.